# When run an eclipse run configuration executes the maven tomcat:run goal, where does Tomcat look to load jars?

Tags: maven, tomcat

I was getting the error "ServletContainer cannot be cast to Servlet" and could not understand why, despite reading related answers in stackoverflow.

My shipment-location-webapp web.xml specifies:

```
<servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
```

And its pom.xml specified the following dependency on the jar file where the superclass(es)  for ServletContainer are found:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

When the shipment-location-webapp run configuration tomcat:run goal was executed, it read the web.xml, tried to load the ServletContainer implementation of Servlet and reports the error:

```
"ServletContainer cannot be cast to Servlet"
```

This is odd, because no such error occurs when we run Tomcat as an eclipse “server”.  It finds the servlet-api jar file either in the Tomcat lib or in the shipment-location-webapp WEB-INF/lib (it can be found in both places).

The problem is resolved by setting the scope for this jar to “provided” in the pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

It makes sense that running Tomcat as a server still works, since this jar file is still found as “provided” in the Tomcat lib, but why does this fix the problem with the run configuration tomcat:run goal???  If it found the file in the Tomcat lib it should have worked without the scope change.  In fact, we can remove servlet-api from the Tomcat lib and it still works!!!  It is no longer “provided” by the container, but by some other “provider”.

It turns out that the tomcat:run plugin opens the servlet-api-2.5.jar (“provided” or not) in my local maven repository.  If I navigate through my .m2/repository/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.5 directories and delete the jar, executing tomcat:run restores it and then you can’t delete it because it is currently open.  But even knowing where tomcat:run finds this jar does not explain why it generates the "ServletContainer cannot be cast to Servlet" error when this dependency is not declared in the pom as “provided”.

So I actually have two questions now:
 1) where does this tomcat:run goal look for jars?
 2) does the "provided" scope really cause it to fetch the jar to my local respository instead of expecting it to be provided?

Comment: Try to keep questions as short and to the point as possible and you'll get better and more answers. Not everyone will read this quantity of text. Asking a question is an art, and it's important to try and find the right balance between providing enough and providing too much information.

Answer (score 0):

Jersey-server dependency is required, add it to your pom.xml and try deploying.

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
     <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
     <version>2.11</version>
  </dependency>
```